# TableView CoreData error: Assertion failure in ... in Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, swift

I implemented Core Data into my app.
If I run it, I get the following error: 
`2014-11-21 13:29:28.400 MyApp[2630:37096] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3318.16.14/UITableView.m:6116`

I don't know what I've done wrong (I'm still learning swift).

This is the function where the error occurred:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell:MyTableViewCell = tableViewNotes.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as MyTableViewCell
    cell.textLabel.text = "\(daten[indexPath.row].aufgabe)"

    return cell
}
```

and the line where the error occurred:

```
var cell:MyTableViewCell = tableViewNotes.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as MyTableViewCell
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
used tabeView in place of tableViewNotes

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell:MyTableViewCell = tabeView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as MyTableViewCell
    cell.textLabel.text = "\(daten[indexPath.row].aufgabe)"

    return cell
}
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer! Now I get a breakpoint in the CoreData library. But it seems to work. I'm a step further.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using your custom cell  Identifier name "Cell" in your storyboard?
If not. Please give this "Cell" to your custom cell Identifier . And I hope it will work

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer. I'm not using storyboard. How can I do this programmatically?

Comment: Then you must have to take a cell in your xib subclass of MyTableViewCell with identifier "Cell". Because method dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier: String, forIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> AnyObject // newer dequeue method guarantees a cell is returned and resized properly, assuming identifier is registered
otherwise you can use 
var cell : MyTableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as MyTableViewCell?
        if cell == nil
        {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        }